# Error 520 on asp.net web app in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis-7.5

Our asp.net web app is returning Error 520 on a page in production though no error in development.
This particular error skips our custom error page and present a different error page with Cloudflare.
As in this image
[image: Error Page here]

When you inspect the page, you see
"Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope"
in console
No error is logged by our logging tools, and we cannot tell why it's skipping our custom error page.

Any direction as to how to solve this?

Comment: Clearly Cloudflare said what you should do under "If you are the owner of this website".

Comment: It's surprising to me why a cloudflare error, we do NOT use cloudflare and we are on a VPS. So we control the server

Comment: `web app is returning Error 520 on a page` Does this error occur when you visit a specific page or when you visit all pages? How you access the server, From server itself or another client machine? Did you try to access it from  server itself and did it show any error message?

Comment: Just a specific page, and access is from a client machine. Error is same when accessed on server. Let me state that, the page is ok the first time it's accessed. The problem occurs when we change selected item of dropdownlist that has AutoPostBack = "True" set. We initially thought this was the cause, but we have checked other pages with same setting on dropdownlist controls and they work.

Comment: Unfortunately seeing that error page indicates the use of Cloudflare. Please ask whoever configured the domain name (DNS) to learn more, as it seems to me that you are only managing the VPS.

Comment: Can you check event viewer to get some error message and IIS log get status code?

Comment: We are following up on the DNS suggestion, @LexLi. There's no entry in the event viewer or IIS log to help us unfortunately

Comment: No. I am not asking you to check event viewer or IIS log. What I am asking is that you find who purchased the domain name and configured the DNS servers for that domain with the initial DNS records. If you are only the server administrator of this VPS, or the web app developer, it is OK that you have no idea what I meant, but that guy (usually a network administrator) should understand what to do.

Comment: We sent them (DNS server) the information to check and get back to us.  We ONLY administer the VPS and also develop the app. Thank you @LexLi for the direction. We are yet to hear from them, will update when we do